# A Class that creates a unit of Stock or a collection of Stocks

Tags: python, python-3.x, object-oriented, classes

I have a dataclass of a single class object 'AStock' as such:

```
@dataclass
class AStock:
    
    code_: Union[str, int]
    force_update_: bool = False
    ticker_: str = field(init=False)
    symbol_: str = field(init=False)
    name_: str = field(init=False)
    sector_: str = field(init=False)
    subsector_: str = field(init=False)
    
    @exception(logger)
    def __post_init__(self) -> None:
        try:
            self.code_ = str(self.code_).zfill(4)
            self.ticker_ = indexer(code=self.code_, arg='ticker')
            self.symbol_ = indexer(code=self.code_, arg='symbol')
            self.name_ = indexer(code=self.code_, arg='full_name')
            self.sector_ = indexer(code=self.code_, arg='sector')
            self.subsector_ = indexer(code=self.code_, arg='subsector')

        except NoStockFound:
            raise
        except Exception as e:
            raise StockException(stock=self) from e
```

What I want to achieve is to create a class object that would initialize a single stock object or a collection of stock objects. So I did a 'Stocks' and a 'Stock' object.

'Stocks' here initializes a group of 'AStock' objects.

```
@dataclass
class Stocks:
    
    code_: List[str]
    force_update_: bool = False
    ticker_: str = field(init=False)
    symbol_: str = field(init=False)
    name_: str = field(init=False)
    sector_: str = field(init=False)
    subsector_: str = field(init=False)
    
    @exception(logger)
    def __post_init__(self) -> None:
        self.ticker_ = [indexer(code, arg='ticker') for code in self.code_]
        self.symbol_ = [indexer(code, arg='symbol') for code in self.code_]
        self.name_ = [indexer(code, arg='full_name') for code in self.code_]
        self.sector_ = [indexer(code, arg='sector') for code in self.code_]
        self.subsector_ = [indexer(code, arg='subsector') for code in self.code_]
    
    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return ', '.join([f'{i[0]}:{i[1]}' for i in list(zip(self.code_, self.ticker_))])
    
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return ', '.join([f'{i[0]}:{i[1]}' for i in list(zip(self.code_, self.ticker_))])
```

and this 'Stock' object here is to handle the creation of 'AStock' or 'Stocks' object.

```
@dataclass
class Stock:
    code: Union[str, int, List[str]]
    force_update: bool = False
    
    @exception(logger)
    def __new__(cls, code, force_update: bool = False):
        if type(code) in [str, int]:
            return AStock(code, force_update)
        
        elif type(code) in [list]:
            return Stocks(code, force_update)
        
        else:
            raise ValueError('Not a valid stock code')
```

So for example:
If `Stock(['1203', '1232'])` will create `Stocks` object and `Stock('1203')` will create a `AStock` object. Just by providing arguments as a List or String it could detect whether to create `AStock` for single stock or `Stocks` for multiple stocks.

However, this is pretty 'hacky' way of using `__new__` to return an either `AStock` object or `Stocks` object. Is there a more elegant way of doing this?

Edited 09 Dec 2021:

From the comments below, I think I should have shown more of my `Stocks` code. For one, yes there are more methods in `Stocks` and `AStock`. Basically, `Stocks.any_methods` will call the same `AStock.any_methods` however it will run it for collection of `codes` and output a `Dict[str, output_data_type_from_AStock]`.

For context here are mode code from `Stocks`.

```
# %%
@dataclass
class Stocks:
    
    code_: List[Union[str, int]]
    force_update_: bool = False
    ticker_: Tuple[str] = field(init=False)
    symbol_: Tuple[str] = field(init=False)
    name_: Tuple[str] = field(init=False)
    sector_: Tuple[str] = field(init=False)
    subsector_: Tuple[str] = field(init=False)
    
    @exception(logger)
    def __post_init__(self) -> None:
        self.ticker_ = tuple([indexer(code, arg='ticker') for code in self.code_])
        self.symbol_ = tuple([indexer(code, arg='symbol') for code in self.code_])
        self.name_ = tuple([indexer(code, arg='full_name') for code in self.code_])
        self.sector_ = tuple([indexer(code, arg='sector') for code in self.code_])
        self.subsector_ = tuple([indexer(code, arg='subsector') for code in self.code_])
    
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return ', '.join([f'{i[0]}:{i[1]}' for i in list(zip(self.code_, self.ticker_))])
    
    def _output_to_dict(self, time_sleep: bool, *args, **kwargs) -> Union[Dict[str, pd.DataFrame], Dict[str, float]]:
        '''
        method takes any method in this class and calls same method of AStock class for each code in codes.
        
        time_sleep = True required for method that utilizes investpy which scrapes from investing.com to avoid
        ip being blocked.
        
        '''
        results = {}
        method_name = inspect.stack()[1][3]
        for code in self.code_:
            if args or kwargs:
                results[code] = getattr(
                    AStock(code, self.force_update_),
                    method_name
                )(*args, **kwargs)
            else:
                results[code] = getattr(
                    AStock(code, self.force_update_),
                    method_name
                )
            if time_sleep:
                time.sleep(5)
        return results
    
    '''
    ------------------------------------------------------
    GENERAL INFO
    ------------------------------------------------------
    '''
    
    @property
    @exception(logger)
    def info_(self) -> Dict[str, pd.DataFrame]:
        return self._output_to_dict(time_sleep = True)

    '''
    ------------------------------------------------------
    FINANCE METRICS
    ------------------------------------------------------
    '''
    
    @property
    @exception(logger)
    def ttm_financials_(self) -> Dict[str, pd.DataFrame]:
        return self._output_to_dict(time_sleep = False)
```

this is the reason why I need another class of `Stock` that will either call `AStock` for a single code of stock or `Stocks` for a list of code of stocks as such:

```
@dataclass
class Stock:
    
    code: Union[str, int, List[str]]
    force_update: bool = False
    
    @exception(logger)
    def __new__(
        cls,
        code: Union[str, int, List[str]],
        force_update: bool = False
    ) -> Union[AStock, Stocks]:
        
        if type(code) in [str, int]:
            return AStock(code, force_update)
        
        elif type(code) in [list]:
            return Stocks(code, force_update)
        
        else:
            raise ValueError('Not a valid stock code')
```

Thanks to @ShapeOfMatter , here is what I did to `Stocks`:

````
class Stocks:
    
    def __init__(self, *codes, force_update_: bool = False):
        self._stocks = [
            AStock(code, force_update_=force_update_) for code in codes
        ]

    def __iter__(self):
        '''
        this makes Stocks an iterable hence could you [s for s in self]
        '''
        yield from self._stocks
    
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return ', '.join([f'{s.code_}:{s.ticker_}' for s in self])
    
    def _dict_apply(self, function: Callable, sleep: bool) -> Any:
        return {f'{stock.code_}': function(stock) for stock in self._stocks if time.sleep(5 * sleep) is None}
    
    def __getattr__(self, attr) -> Any:
        candidate = lambda x: getattr(x, attr, None)
        return partial(self._dict_apply, function=candidate)(sleep=True)
    
```
````

Comment: What is `indexer` from? Please show all of your code.

Comment: Why exactly do you want a class that initializes to something that's not even an instance of itself instead of just using a function?

Answer (score 3):

**Prefer ordinary naming whenever possible**. If a class is called `Stock`,
that's a perfectly sensible name: nearly all English speakers will correctly
assume that it refers to a single stock. That's how the language works and you
should use the language conventions to your advantage. There's no need to
overcomplicate things by giving the class a name like `AStock`. Gluing an
indefinite article to the name doesn't help at all; it just produces a
non-idiomatic name.

**Don't create a class merely because you need a collection of instances**.
Python already has handy collection classes: lists, tuples, dicts, and so
forth. If you have a bunch of `Stock` instances and need to operate on them as
a collection, just do it with ordinary Python collections – in your case,
probably with a list. The only time you need to bother with creating a special
class to represent such a collection is if the collection itself requires
meaningful attributes or behaviors. At least in the code you've shown us, the
`Stocks` class has none of that: it's purely a derivative of the underlying
`Stock` class (meaning the one you called `AStock`). Bottom line: just use a list unless your plans are different than
what we've seen.

**Don't create a class if a simple function will do**. There is nothing
class-like in your current code for `Stock`. It's just an `if-else` mechanism
to create one thing or a collection of things. Classes are attributes and
behavior. You have only behavior. Use a function for stuff like that.

Comment: see update above.

Comment: @mrkgoh I believe the recommended policy is that you not change the question after people write reviews. Take what you learned and post a new question with new code. Otherwise, the code-under-review is a moving target, which would make it a bit frustrating to the people trying to help.

Comment: will take note of not change the question next time. Happy if you would take another look anyway. Value your input. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're using dataclasses and typehints*, so you're doing reasonably well. Now you should learn about variable-length arguments. They're nicer (in my opinion) than checking to see if the argument is a list.

Also here's some fun with generators and unpacking, which may or may not be appropriate for your uses.

```py
# totally untested.
def stocks(*codes: Union[str, int], force_update: bool = False) -> Iterable[Stock]:
    for code in codes:
        yield Stock(code, force_update)

# make a list:
my_stocks = list(  # if we weren't using a generator, we wouldn't need this.
    stocks('1203', '1232')
)

# unpack just one:
my_stock, = stocks(2344)

# unpack just one, without binding to a variable:
buy(next(stocks(2344)))
```

<sub>* you've got a type-checker running right?)</sub>

Comment: see update above.

Answer (score 1):

## Regarding the edit:

You seem to have fixated on a bad solution (your `Stock` class) to a simple problem (working with single stocks and groups of stocks in a fluid way). All [FMc's points](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/270751/200133) are still good.

The way you have it written now, what should MyPy think the type of `Stock(87)` is? How long before a consumer of your API calls `isinstance` on one of these objects? **Don't find solutions to these problems; scrap your existing solution.**  `Stock` should just be a function.

Your `Stocks` class is also problematic. There are things we'd expect to be able to do with a collection that we can't, like iterate over the members. It's also inefficient to be (re)creating all the `AStock`s every time a method is called. **Are you sure you can't just let your users write comprehensions over lists of `AStock` objects?**

If you can't, consider something like:

```py
StockID = Union[str, int]

class Stocks:

    def __init__(self, codes: Iterable[StockID], force_update: bool = False):
        self._stocks = [AStock(code, force_update=force_update)
                        for code in codes]

    def __iter_(self):
        yield from self._stocks
    
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return ', '.join([f'{s.code}:{s.ticker}' for s in self])
    
    def dict_apply(self,
                   function: Callable[[AStock, Any...] pd.DataFrame],  # ??
                   *args,
                   **kwargs,
                   time_sleep: bool = False)
                   -> Union[Dict[str, pd.DataFrame], Dict[str, float]]:
        '''time_sleep = True required for method that utilizes investpy which scrapes from investing.com to avoid ip being blocked.'''
        return {function(stock, *args, **kwargs)  # it's fine if args/kwargs are empty.
                for stock in self
                if (time_sleep and time.sleep(5)  # IDK if this works
                   ) or True}

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        # If we're careful, this is probably less fragile than inspecting the call stack. Still kinda sketchy!
        candidate = getAttr(AStock, attr, None)
        if callable(candidate):
            return functools.partial(self.dict_apply, function=candidate)
        else:
            raise AttributeError, attr
```

The above includes some guesswork on my part, and there are certainly other options. One option is to actually *inherit from* `list`; this can be fun, but has its own pitfalls...

Comment: ShapeOfMatter, thank you for your guidance and being patient with one hedious python coder such as myself. Your code above allowed me to improve my Stocks class. Here is what I did: <See new edit above>